# PHP Version to use for Facebook SDK 3.1.1

Tags: facebook, php-5.3, php-5.2

What is the best version of PHP to run for Facebook SDK 3.1.1? I am currently running PHP 5.2.6, but was wondering if 5.3.8 is better? Is there any thing wrong running either/or?

Answer (score 1):

You will need **PHP5.2+** to use the Facebook SDK. I tried looking in their documentation for system requirements, but Facebook's docs aren't brilliant.

Using a more recent version of PHP is completely up to you and your application, as it won't give you any noticeable benefits.

Comment: This was very helpful. I tried looking everywhere too but couldn't find any documentation on it either. In your opinion, is there any benifits of migrating at this point to 5.3.8 in general?

Comment: @alwayslearning The only benefits I see are being able to use PHP5.3 features in your codebase. With regards to Facebook SDK specifically, there won't be any benefits by upgrading.